# Auth0 callback URL mismatch and where do we set the callback URL

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I just downloaded the quick-start code of React from Auth0 . I changed the callback url from window.location.pathname to 'http://localhost:3000/profile'.

`const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, 'http://localhost:3000/profile');`

In Auth0 application setting, I also changed the Allowed Callback URLs to http://localhost:3000/profile.

However, it shows that "http://localhost:3000 is not in the list of allowed callback URLs". It makes me think that I failed to change redirect callback url in react-auth0-spa file.

react-auth0-spa:

`````
import createAuth0Client from "@auth0/auth0-spa-js";
console.log(window.location.pathname)
const DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK = () =>
  window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, 'http://localhost:3000/profile');

export const Auth0Context = React.createContext();
export const useAuth0 = () => useContext(Auth0Context);````
`````

```
  children,
  onRedirectCallback = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK,
  ...initOptions
}) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [auth0Client, setAuth0] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [popupOpen, setPopupOpen] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const initAuth0 = async () => {
      const auth0FromHook = await createAuth0Client(initOptions);
      setAuth0(auth0FromHook);

      if (
        window.location.search.includes("code=") &&
        window.location.search.includes("state=")
      ) {
        const { appState } = await auth0FromHook.handleRedirectCallback();
        onRedirectCallback(appState);
      }

      const isAuthenticated = await auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated();

      setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);

      if (isAuthenticated) {
        const user = await auth0FromHook.getUser();
        setUser(user);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };
    initAuth0();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
 const loginWithPopup = async (params = {}) => {
    setPopupOpen(true);
    try {
      await auth0Client.loginWithPopup(params);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setPopupOpen(false);
    }
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setUser(user);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };

  const handleRedirectCallback = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
    const user = await auth0Client.getUser();
    setLoading(false);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUser(user);

  };
  return (
    <Auth0Context.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        user,
        loading,
        popupOpen,
        loginWithPopup,
        handleRedirectCallback,
        getIdTokenClaims: (...p) => auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims(...p),
        loginWithRedirect: (...p) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p),
        getTokenSilently: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenSilently(...p),
        getTokenWithPopup: (...p) => auth0Client.getTokenWithPopup(...p),
        logout: (...p) => auth0Client.logout(...p)
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that I should change redirect_url to window.location.origin + '/profile' from window.location.origin instead of changing DEFAULT_REDIRECT_CALLBACK. However, I am still not sure how redirect_uri works.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Auth0Provider
        domain={config.domain}
        client_id={config.clientId}
        redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/profile'}
        onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
        <App />
    </Auth0Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```